# Issue with event handler in EXT JS 4 with card layout

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am working on adding an event handler to a "card layout" Panel.

The problem I am having is I am getting the below error in the Google Chrome console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: navigate is not defined
```

This is my EXTJS code file:

```
Ext.define('COMP.app.DailyBulletin', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
alias: 'widget.dailybulletin',
height: 300,
width: 200,
layout: 'card',
bodyStyle: 'padding:15px',
activeItem: 0, // index or id
bbar: ['->', {
    id: 'card-prev',
    text: '&laquo; Previous',
    handler: function(btn){
        navigate(btn.up("panel"), "prev");
    },
    disabled: true
},{
    id: 'card-next',
    text: 'Next &raquo;',
    handler: function(btn){
        navigate(btn.up("panel"), "next");
    },
}],
items: [{
    id: 'card-0',
    html: 'page 0'
},{
    id: 'card-1',
    html: 'page 1'
}],

    navigate: function(panel, direction){
        var layout = panel.getLayout();
        layout[direction]();
        Ext.getCmp('card-prev').setDisabled(!layout.getPrev());
        Ext.getCmp('card-next').setDisabled(!layout.getNext());
},
});
```

When I debug the JS in the Google Chrome Developer Tool I can see the issue is that the event handler can't access the navigate function, as it doesn't think it's there. If I just move the code from the navigate function into the event handler and change the layout and direction from expecting parameters to just getting them directly the navigation works fine. This tells me my issue is in how I am calling the navigate function and that I am doing something wrong there.

I'm new to EXT JS and any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Ext.define('COMP.app.DailyBulletin', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.dailybulletin',
    height: 300,
    width: 200,
    layout: 'card',
    bodyStyle: 'padding:15px',
    activeItem: 0, // index or id

    items: [{
        id: 'card-0',
        html: 'page 0'
    }, {
        id: 'card-1',
        html: 'page 1'
    }],

    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            bbar: ['->', {
                id: 'card-prev',
                text: '&laquo; Previous',
                scope: this,
                handler: function(btn) {
                    this.navigate(btn.up("panel"), "prev");
                },
                disabled: true
            }, {
                id: 'card-next',
                text: 'Next &raquo;',
                handler: function(btn) {
                    scope: this,
                    this.navigate(btn.up("panel"), "next");
                },
            }]
        });
        this.callParent();
    },

    navigate: function(panel, direction) {
        var layout = panel.getLayout();
        layout[direction]();
        Ext.getCmp('card-prev').setDisabled(!layout.getPrev());
        Ext.getCmp('card-next').setDisabled(!layout.getNext());
    },
});
```

Comment: I think you have a typo too :)

Comment: Evan, I took your solution and tried it and I received this error in my Google Chrome console. I think your solution makes sense but I'm not sure what is causing this error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setSize' of undefined

Comment: Don't just copy and paste random code, you should at least look at it first. Answer updated.